# How to distinguish a deliberate, controller-generated 404 from an actual error in a REST API?

Tags: json, api, rest, http, microservices

In a JSON-REST service architecture (following [these patterns](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) for methods and response codes) we often need to generate a deliberate 404 response - for example, if `GET /users/123` is routed to a controller, which is then unable to find a User entity with ID `123`, we return a 404 response, which in many cases will include a JSON payload with an error message/code/etc.

Now, when we provide a client for a specific API, we want the client to behave differently under different conditions. For example, if we point the client to the wrong host, we might get a 404 not found from that host - as opposed to the 404 we might get for an invalid User ID if we do reach the service.

In this case, a "404 User ID not found" is not an error, as far as the client is concerned - as opposed to any other "404 Not Found", which should cause the client to throw an exception.

My question is, how do you distinguish between these 404 errors?

Solely based on the response?

By adding a header to indicate a valid response?

Or some other way?

Comment: Is `GET /users/123` an *allowed* action for any client?  Or is only user123 allowed to view that, etc?  Because a "[403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)" may be more accurate (and RESTful) if it's due to any sort of security issue.

Comment: Yes, we issue 403 codes if the service request is denied - those are not as easily mistaken for anything else. But in the case of a 404, there could be several reasons, such as hitting the wrong server, the service is down, the service isn't routing the request properly, etc. - so the client needs some way to distinguish a "successful" 404, for which the client might return `null`, from an actual error, for which the client might raise an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK to return 404 in both cases. As 4xx codes are client relevant codes, it is also OK to return content even if there was an error.

Now, deciding what kind of 404 it was can be decided based on the body of the response. Remember, that the response should carry a `mime-type` that is compatible with the `Accept` header the client supplied. So if the client "knows" your specific error-describing format, your server can answer with a more detailed description.

This way both the server can decide whether the client would understand a detailed response with the 404, **and** the client also understands when it just got a regular 404, or one with a message it can process.

This would be both semantically correct, and compatible with HTTP.

Comment: I was starting to think along those lines, but your point about checking the content-type on the client is very important - no need to attempt to parse HTML as JSON if the response you got came from the wrong host.